# Remove digits from a string when they are followed by a letter pattern

Tags: python, python-re

I have three strings as follows

```
ex1 = "All is good 24STREET"
ex2 = "Is this the weight 2.5OZ"
ex3 = "Feeling good 100pc"
```

I want to remove only the digits when they are followed by '**OZ**' or '**pc**' but not with others.

```
**results**
    ex1 = "All is good 24STREET"
    ex2 = "Is this the weight OZ"
    ex3 = "Feeling good pc"
```

I tried with '**str.replace('\d+', '')**' but this removes all digits and also not the "dot"

Comment: why `24` not removed in 1st line?

Comment: *I want to remove only the digits when they are followed by **'OZ' or 'pc'** but not with others.* @LeiYang

Comment: Only digits followed by 'oz' and 'pc' pattern should be removed. If anything else (like 23BUS), the digits shouldn't be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re

ex1 = "All is good 24STREET"
ex2 = "Is this the weight 2.5OZ"
ex3 = "Feeling good 100pc"
reg = re.compile(r'[\d.]+(?=OZ|pc)')
print(reg.sub('', ex1))
print(reg.sub('', ex2))
print(reg.sub('', ex3))
```

Output:

> All is good 24STREET
>
> Is this the weight OZ
>
> Feeling good pc